# How do I run multiple functions on text in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am ajaxing in some text from a PHP script and trying to have it fade in to the page. However, I can't get the fadeIn() function to behave. Here's where I am:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#generate").click(function(){
            $("#quote p").load("sendText.php");
        });
    });
    </script>

<input type="submit" style="background-image: url(hitmebutton.png); height:8em; width:23em;" id="generate" value=""><br />
    <div id="quote"><p></p></div>
```

So sendText.php echos out some text. To get it to fade in when the button is clicked, I tried just doing

```
$("#quote p").load("sendText.php").fadeIn();
```

I also tried doing

```
$("#generate").click(function(){
        $("#quote p").load("sendText.php");
        $("#quote p").fadeIn();
    });
```

But neither worked. How do I get fadeIn() to apply? I feel like there's something small I'm missing.

Comment: The `<p>` should be hidden before you try to fade it in. Is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to fade in the text when it is loaded. Furthermore, for `fadeIn` to work, the element must be hidden first. Try:

```
$("#quote p").load("sendText.php", function(){
    $(this).hide().fadeIn();
});
```

You could also hide the element before you load the content.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$("#generate").click(function(){             
    $("#quote p").load("sendText.php", function(){ 
       $(this).hide().fadeIn('slow'); 
    });
});
```